Integrating $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\cos(1-3x)}{x^2+4x+13} $ using complex analysis
I'm trying to solve the improper integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\cos(1-3x)}{x^2+4x+13}$$
Using complex analysis. Now, if there wasn't the term $\cos(1-3x)$ in the numerator, I would be able to solve it. But I don't know how I can answer this question when its involved.
Any help is appreciated.
I tried solving it by using @J.G. 's suggestion and here's how it went
$$e^i\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-3ix}}{x^2+4x+13} $$
The denominator has 2 conjugate roots and one was outside the semicircle, so I ignored it.
I was able to find only one residue (a simple pole) at $z = -2+3i$. So we want
$$I=\operatorname{Re} (e^i2\pi i \operatorname{res}_{z=-2+3i}\frac{ze^{-3iz}}{z^2+4z+13} )$$
And since its a pole I can use the limit formula for finding its residue.
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^i2\pi i \lim_{z\rightarrow-2+3i}(z - (-2+3i))\frac{ze^{-3iz}}{(z - (-2+3i) )(z-(-2-3i))} )$$
$$I=\operatorname{Re} (e^i2\pi i \lim_{z\rightarrow-2+3i}\frac{ze^{-3iz}}{(z-(-2-3i))} )$$
Substituting $z=-2+3i$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^i 2\pi i \frac{(-2+3i)e^{-3i(-2+3i)}}{(-2+3i-(-2-3i))} )$$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^i 2\pi i \frac{(-2+3i)e^{6i+9}}{6i} )$$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^i 2\pi i \frac{(-2+3i)e^{6i+9}}{6i} )$$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^{7i}e^{9} 2\pi\frac{(-2+3i)}{6} )$$
And then expressing $e$ in terms of $\sin$ and $cos$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} (e^{9} (\cos7 + i\sin7) 2\pi\frac{(-2+3i)}{6} )$$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} \frac{e^9}{6}(2\pi\cos7 + i2\pi\sin7)(-2+3i)$$
$$I = \operatorname{Re} \frac{e^9}{6}(-4\pi\cos7-6pi\sin7) + \frac{e^9 i}{6}(6\pi\cos7+6\pi\sin7)$$
And picking out the real part would give us
$$ I = \frac{e^9}{6}(-4\pi\cos7-6\pi\sin7)$$
Can anybody spot any mistakes?

Hint: replace the cosine with $\exp(i-3ix)$, use the residue theorem with a semicircular contour in the upper hair of the complex plane, then take the real part.

@J.G. I did the substitution as you suggested and took the real part, I'm not sure if my answer is correct but I am getting $\frac{e^9}{6}(-4\pi \cos(7) - 6\pi\sin(7))$

That's close, but one of the terms needs a +
sign. If you edit your calculations into the question, we can diagnose your sign error.

Sorry, I've just realised what the problem is. Because there's an $e^{-3iz}$ factor, we actually need the arc in the lower half of the complex plane. (The resulting contour needs a clockwise tour, so the residue theorem uses a $-2\pi i$ factor.)

@J.G. I See, so that mean we should use the singularity in the lower half of the complex plane?

Correct. Note that minus signs cancel in $(-2\pi I)/(-6i)$, so the calculation is only slightly different from what you did. (Alternatively, if we start from $\cos(3x-1)=\Re\exp(3ix-i)$ we can use the upper half-plane after all.)

You have\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\cos(1-3x)}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\bigl(\cos(1)\cos(3x)+\sin(1)\sin(3x)\bigr)}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\cos(1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\cos(3x)}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx+\\&\phantom=\quad+\sin(1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(3x)}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\cos(1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\operatorname{Re}(e^{3ix})}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx+\\&\phantom=\quad+\sin(1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\operatorname{Im}(e^{3ix})}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\cos(1)\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{3ix}}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx\right)+\\&\phantom=\quad+\sin(1)\operatorname{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{3ix}}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx\right).\end{align}But\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{3ix}}{x^2+4x+13}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{3ix}}{(x+2)^2+9}\,\mathrm dx\\&=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=-2+3i}\frac{ze^{3iz}}{(z+2)^2+9}\\&=2\pi i\left(\left(\frac12+\frac i3\right)e^{-9-6i}\right)\\&=\frac\pi{e^9}\left(-\frac23+i\right)(\cos(6)-\sin(6)i)\\&=\frac\pi{e^9}\left(-\frac23\cos(6)+\sin(6)+\left(\cos(6)+\frac23\sin(6)\right)i\right).\end{align}Therefore, the integral that you want to compute is equal to\begin{multline}\frac\pi{e^9}\left(-\frac23\cos(1)\cos(6)+\cos(1)\sin(6)+\sin(1)\cos(6)+\frac23\sin(1)\sin(6)\right)=\\=\frac\pi{e^9}\left(-\frac23\cos(7)+\sin(7)\right).\end{multline}

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos (1-3 x)}{x^2+4 x+13} d x \\
& =\Re\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-(1-3 x) i}}{x^2+4 x+13} d x\right) \text {, via } x \mapsto x-2 \\
& =\Re\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2) e^{(3 x-7) i}}{x^2+9} d x\right) \\
& =\Re\left(e^{-7 i} \underbrace{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2) e^{3 x i}}{x^2+9}}_J d x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path $$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) ,$$
and the Residue Theorem, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(x-2) e^{3 x i}}{x^2+9} d x\\&=\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_\gamma \frac{(z-2) e^{3 z i}}{z^2+9} d z \\
& =2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow 3 i} \frac{(z-2) e^{3 z i}}{z+3 i} \\
& =2 \pi i \cdot \frac{3 i-2}{6 i e^9}\\&=\frac{\pi(3 i-2)}{3 e^9}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\Re\left(e^{-7 i} \cdot \frac{\pi(3 i-2)}{3 e^9}\right) \\
& =\frac{\pi}{3 e^9} \Re[(\cos 7-i \sin 7)(3 i-2)] \\
& =\frac{\pi}{3 e^9}(3 \sin 7-2 \cos 7)
\end{aligned}
$$
